# Getting OS error on NotoColorEmoji font using Python Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use NotoColorEmoji font. But Getting OS error when I run the code.
I am not sure why its happening.

Here is my code :

```
from PIL import ImageFont

FONT_PATH = './NotoColorEmoji.ttf' //NotoColorEmoji font directory
font_size = 65
font = ImageFont.truetype(FONT_PATH, size=font_size)
```

Here is the error that I found :

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(FONT_PATH, size=font_size)
   File "/home/peter/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 844, in truetype
     return freetype(font)
   File "/home/peter/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 841, in freetype
     return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
   File "/home/peter/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 194, in __init__
     font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine=layout_engine
 OSError: invalid pixel size
```

Anyone can help on this issue?
Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Python 3.7 could not handle Unicode characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane. That includes emojis. The first thing I would try is installing a more recent version of Python. You don't have to  (and should not) upgrade your existing installation. Just install 3.10 alongside 3.7 and see if that makes the problem go away.

Comment: Comments are introduced with `#` in Python, not double-slashes.

Comment: I found that there is only one valid size for NotoColorEmoji: 109
with that size i pass the OSError: invalid pixel size error, but then get OSError: invalid size handle when drawing...